# Any VS C# way to list all `throw new NotImplementedException()` methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any lazy way to list all methods that only have `throw new NotImplementedException();` in their body... that is built-in Visual Studio C#? Something similar to the `(Todo) Task List Pane` but that would only list such empty throwing place-holder methods that are clearly pending/awaiting implementation?

It would be helpful for implementing interfaces and easily keeping track of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hack that you can use that's evil, but works.  Add the following class somewhere in your project.  Just be sure to get rid of it before releasing it to production, or make it compatible with the original.

```
namespace System
{
    [Obsolete("Fix this")]
    public class NotImplementedException : Exception 
    {
        public NotImplementedException() : base() {}
        public NotImplementedException(string message) : base(message) {}
        public NotImplementedException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) {}
        protected NotImplementedException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) {}
    }
}
```

This will cause all NotImplementedExceptions in your code to show up as warnings.

This is a type interception technique for your source code that I've used once or twice before.  I don't normally recommend doing stuff like this unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: This works but it's like a shortcut to Find Everywhere plus it clutters the Output. But it does the job making them really hard to miss.

Comment: Eve if a bit hacky, this is the easiest method to achieve the result. It helps make sure you don't miss any of them methods due to the warnings in your build Output. And it's easy to turn off too.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried `CTRL+SHIFT+F` and searching `*.cs` files for `NotImplementedException`?

Comment: :) Good one! Of course that's what I do but I was hoping for a more friendly way of doing it that I might have missed being quite new at the C# game. A dedicated pane could allow filtering by namespace, class, etc... With all the tooling C# has *(compared to C++ where I come from)*, this feature should exist. :)

Comment: If you have ReSharper, the "Find usages" window can do that.

Comment: He's asking for something similar to the (Todo) Task List Pane. Look for the *Custom Tokens* for the Task List Pane, it can probably help:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txtwdysk.aspx

Comment: @thepirat000 unfortunately custom tokens would still require you to add a comment.  If the OP were willing to add a comment, they'd probably just add a `// todo` comment and not bother with an SO question...

Comment: @Brandon Right. If I hit implement interface to provide all method stubs for me, it's hard to comment in them.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Object Browser (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>).
Find the `NotImplementedException` class.
Right-click it and select Find all references.

Comment: This I like better! If only I could save a shortcut to the `Find All References of NotImplementedException`... it would be perfect.

Comment: @CodeAngry There kind of is one, `Ctrl+K, R`, but the cursor needs to be inside the `NotImplementedException` in code. So you could type `new NotImplementedException();` at a random place in your code and press that, then delete it.